# How can I delete all the gdb related windows/buffers after `q` in gdb CLI window

Tags: buffers, debugging, gud, kill-buffer, gdb

I use `(setq gdb-many-windows t)` and `(setq gdb-show-main t)` configurations in my `init.el`, so after executing `M-x gdb`, there will be six windows in the frame, after typing `q` in the main gdb cli window to finish debugging, how can I quit/delete all the gdb related windows/buffers (including the current gdb CLI, locals, breakpoints, stack frames...) and just leave the source code buffer open at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

After googling around and tweaking the code snippets from the internet, I got this solution and it works as expected:

```
(defvar all-gud-modes
  '(gud-mode comint-mode gdb-locals-mode gdb-frames-mode  gdb-breakpoints-mode)
  "A list of modes when using gdb")
(defun kill-all-gud-buffers ()
  "Kill all gud buffers including Debugger, Locals, Frames, Breakpoints.
Do this after `q` in Debugger buffer."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
        (let ((count 0))
          (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
                (set-buffer buffer)
                (when (member major-mode all-gud-modes)
                  (setq count (1+ count))
                  (kill-buffer buffer)
                  (delete-other-windows))) ;; fix the remaining two windows issue
          (message "Killed %i buffer(s)." count))))
```

You can bind the `kill-all-gud-buffers` to a key or `defalias` it to a short name or even change the function name so you can type it easily.

Comment: In realgud, the situation is both more complicated and simpler. There can be many debug sessions going on. But the command buffer for a single debug session has a list of the source code buffers associated with it.  If you want to write the corresponding function for realgud, you would use field srcbuf-list of the buffer-local variable realgud-cmdbuf-info, I'd consider adding this to the code base.